# Type casting char array to char **

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, type-conversion

If I do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char **arr2D;

char arr1D [5 * 10];

int main (void)
{
    ((arr2D)arr1D)[0][0] = '_';

    printf("%c", arr1D[0]);

    return(0);
}
```

I receive crash, which suggests undefined behavior.
Why can't I do this ?

Comment: @Inline - Nope. The extra star matters.

Comment: @Inline In way way this is even close to duplicate now ?

Answer (score 4):

1. `char arr1D [5 * 10];` - is zero initialized.
2. `((arr2D)arr1D)[0]` - reinterprets the memory pointed to by `arr1D` as a pointer to char*. This has an unspecified address (zero byte pattern isn't necessarily the NULL address).
3. `((arr2D)arr1D)[0][0]` - derefrences that unspecified address. Undefined behavior.

Your naming also suggests a misconception common about pointers and arrays. Arrays aren't pointers. And pointers aren't arrays.

Arrays **decay** into pointers to the first element.

`char[2][2]` is a 2D char array that will decay to `char(*)[2]` (a pointer to an array).
`char**` is not a 2D char array, it's a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Ahh yes.. should've figured it out. So there is no way I can do this trick.

Comment: @Malina - I find that good programming is as devoid of tricks as possible. Code that requires a lot of explanations on the side to understand should be constrained to the smallest scope possible.

Comment: Bad news for me I guess. I feel good when I find myself a (un)good trick. This is just a pretty mediocre trick. (And I wouldn't even call it "trick") Pity attempt to find a good trick.

Comment: @Malina - I won't argue such tricks are fun. But down the lines, when you have to review *your own* code months or years later. The only one tricked is yourself.

Comment: `arr1D` does not have an unspecified address. C allows all manner of crazy pointer conversions, as long as the contents aren't de-referenced. If the `char**` would have gotten cast back to the correct type `char(*)[2]` then it would point at the address of `arr1D` still.

Comment: @Lundin - I never claimed `arr1D` has an unspecified address. I claimed that the content at `*arr1D`, when reinterpreted as a `char*` is an unspecified address.